# Which namespace configuration for composer

Tags: php, composer-php, phpmailer

I'm trying to use PHPMailer through composer.

I'm using namespace and PSR-4 autoloading for my app

My file organisation is like this

```
-bin
  -controllers
    - Controller.php (namespace bin\controllers)
  -vendor
    -phpmailer
      -phpmailer
       -src
         PHPMailer.php (namespace HPMailer\PHPMailer)
```

In composer.json, I wrote this

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"bin\\vendor\\phpmailer\\": "bin/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php"}
}
```

But when I use

```
<?php

namespace bin\controllers;

use bin\vendor\phpmailer\PHPMailer;

abstract class Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
    }
}
```

I got a fatal error :

> require_once(): Failed opening required '/Users/thomas/Library/Mobile
>   Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/saveProject/bin/../bin/vendor/phpmailer/PHPMailer.php'

How I could configure the namespace to use the class correctly?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up paths and [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php); for the most part they are independent, but PSR-4 and friends help to map one to the other.

PHPMailer only supports namespaces as of version 6.0, which is not yet released, though you can of course use a pre-release version.

```
use bin\vendor\phpmailer\PHPMailer;
```

Should be:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

The `use` keyword is used to import an entity from another namespace into the current one - note that this is conceptually different from including a file with `include` / `require`.

It looks like you're mixing up namespaces in your own app too - typically you'd use a namespace that's based on a `<vendorname>\<projectname>` pattern, so your example controller might be :

```
namespace MyCompany\MyProject;

class MyMailController...
```

Or you could make use of multiple namespaces within your own project like this:

```
namespace MyCompany\MyProject\Controllers;

class Mail...
```

which would define the `MyCompany\MyProject\Controllers\Mail` class.

Comment: My mistake, thanks for the quick and correct answer :)